# solve an quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I was reading a document , where  I stucked in figuring out this equation.

$f(k)= k^2-nk+\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$. This is a quadratic function of $k$. It is minimized when 
$k=\frac{n}{2}$ (the $k$ coordinate of the vertex of the parabola that is the graph of this function) and maximized at  the endpoints of the domain, namely $k=1$ and $k=n-1$.

please explain how it is ??

Comment: What is your question exactly? Also, a quadratic equation has domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What does your question have to do with differential equations, the (only) tag you used. Isn't this just a precalculus question?

Comment: As asked earlier,exactly what is the domain for $k$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$f(k) = \left(k-\frac{n}2\right)^2+\frac{n^2-2n}4$$
So as the distance of $k$ from $\dfrac{n}2$ increases, the function increases.